# Is it true that a default constructor is synthesized for every class that does not define one?

Tags: c++

If the class doesn't have the constructor, will the compiler make one default constructor for it ?

> Programmers new to C++ often have two common misunderstandings:
>
> That a default constructor is synthesized for every class that does
>   not define one

from the book Inside the C++ Object Model

I am at a loss...

Comment: AFAIK every class has a default constructor, however it is best to create it yourself (at least I do it).

Comment: This quote is at the end of a section that explains at length when exactly a default constructor is synthesized. You should probably read this section and not jump directly to the end.

Comment: Yes, It is not a good question at all...I just want to listen what will you guys say

Comment: You need to make your question understandable so we'll actually have something useful to say - but I think the book is getting at problems people run into when stuff that they expect to automatically happen doesn't happen, though either the book doesn't explain very well or there's a lot more content before they throw that line out there.

Comment: As Luc Touraille states in his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9637074/297696 - this is definitely described in the book, and has a different meaning from what we thought.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is well explained in the section from which this quote is taken. I will not paraphrase it in its entirety, but here is a short summary of the section content.

First of all, you need to understand the following terms: `implicitly-declared`, `implicitly-defined`, `trivial`, `non-trivial` and `synthesized` (a term that is used by Stanley Lippman, but is not used in the standard).

***implicitly-declared***

A constructor is `implicitly-declared` for a class if there is no `user-declared` constructor in this class. For example, this class `struct T { };` does not declare any constructor, so the compiler implicitly declares a default constructor. On the other hand, this class `struct T { T(int); };` declares a constructor, so the compiler will not declare an implicit default constructor. You will not be able to create an instance of `T` without parameters, unless you define your own default constructor.

***implicitly-defined***

An `implicitly-declared` constructor is `implicitly-defined` when it is used, i.e. when an instance is created without parameters. Assuming the following class `struct T { };`, the line `T t;` will trigger the definition of `T::T()`. Otherwise, you would have a linker error since the constructor would be declared but not defined. **However, an implicitly-defined constructor does not necessarily have any code associated with it!** A default constructor is ***synthesized*** (meaning that some code is created for it) by the compiler only under certain circumstances.

***trivial constructor***

An `implicitly-declared` default constructor is `trivial` when:

- its class has no virtual functions and no virtual base classes and
- its base classes have `trivial` constructors and
- all its non-static members have `trivial` constructors.

In this case, the default compiler has nothing to do, so there is no code synthesized for it. For instance, in the following code

```
struct Trivial
{
    int i;
    char * pc;
};

int main()
{
    Trivial t;
}
```

the construction of `t` does not involve any operations (you can see that by looking at the generated assembly: no constructor is called to construct `t`).

***non-trivial***

On the other hand, if the class does not meet the three requirements stated above, its `implicitly-declared` default constructor will be `non-trivial`, meaning that it will involve some operations that must be performed in order to respect the language semantics. In this case, the compiler will `synthesize` an implementation of the constructor performing these operations.

For instance, consider the following class:

```
struct NonTrivial
{
    virtual void foo();
};
```

Since it has a virtual member function, its default constructor **must** set the virtual table pointer to the correct value (assuming the implementation use a virtual method table, of course).

Similarly, the constructor of this class

```
struct NonTrivial
{
    std::string s;
};
```

**must** call the string default constructor, as it is not `trivial`. To perform these operations, the compiler generates the code for the default constructor, and calls it anytime you create an instance without parameters. You can check this by looking at the assembly corresponding to this instantiation `NonTrivial n;` (you should see a function call, unless the constructor has been inlined).

---

**Summary**

When you don't provide any constructor for your class, the compiler implicitly declares a default one. If you try to use it, the compiler implicitly defines it, if it can (it is not always possible, for instance when a class has a non-default-constructible member). However, this implicit definition does not imply the generation of any code. The compiler needs to generate code for the constructor (synthesize it) only if it is non-trivial, meaning that it involves certain operations needed to implement the language semantics.

---

**N.B.**

Stanley B Lippman's "Inside the C++ object model" and this answer deals with (a possible) implementation of C++, not its semantics. As a consequence, none of the above can be generalized to all compilers: as far as I know, an implementation is perfectly allowed to generate code even for a trivial constructor. From the C++ user point of view, all that matters is the "implicitly-declared/defined` aspect (and also the trivial/non-trivial distinction, as it has some implications (for instance, an object of a class with non-trivial constructor cannot be a member of a union)).

Comment: +1 - Interesting, interesting. Guess I need to take a look at this book.

Comment: wait, whats the synthesized mean?

Comment: Summary is incorrect.  There are several more conditions on availability of a default constructor than simply "no user-declared constructors".

Comment: @BenVoigt: I may have forgot some conditions, could you elaborate? I read this sentence in the C++03 standard (§12.1.5) and did not dig further: `If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a default constructor is implicitly-declared.`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: `synthesized` mean (in Stanley Lippman's book) that some code is generated for it by the implementation (I did not feel the need to make a paragraph to explain it as I introduce the notion in the `implicitly-defined` paragraph).

Comment: @LucTouraille: Ah sorry.  I knew the other terms so I didn't actually read those paragraphs.

Comment: @LucTouraille: in your Summary,"the compiler implicitly declares a default one", so the there must be a constructor declared, but only defined if necessary?Is that right?

Comment: @user974349: That's right, the constructor is defined only when you use it to create an object.

Answer (score 11):

I think the misconception is:

> That a default constructor is synthesized for every class that does not define one

That people think the default constructor, which accepts no arguments, will always be generated if you don't declare it yourself.

However, this is not true, because if you declare any constructor yourself, the default one will not be automatically created.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int x) {}; // No default constructor will be generated now
};
```

This will lead to problems like when beginners expect to use `MyClass` like this:

```
MyClass mc;
```

Which won't work because there is no default constructor that accepts no args.

**edit** as OP is still a little confused.

Imagine that my `MyClass` above was this:

```
class MyClass {
};

int main() {
    MyClass m;
}
```

That would compile, because the compiler will autogenerate the default constructor `MyClass()` because `MyClass` was used.

Now take a look at this:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {

};

int main() {
    std::cout << "exiting\n";
}
```

If this were the only code around, the compiler wouldn't even bother generating the default constructor, because `MyClass` is never used.

Now this:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int x = 5) { _x = x; }
    int _x;
};

int main() {
    MyClass m;
    std::cout << m._x;
}
```

The compiler doesn't generate default constructor `MyClass()`, because the class already has a constructor defined by me. This will work, and `MyClass(int x = 5)` works as your default constructor because it can accept no arguments, but it wasn't generated by the compiler.

And finally, where beginners might run into a problem:

```
class MyClass() {
public:
    MyClass(int x) { _x = x; }
    int _x;
};

int main() {
    MyClass m;
}
```

The above will throw you an error during compilation, because `MyClass m` needs a default constructor (no arguments) to work, but you already declared a constructor that takes an `int`. The compiler will not generate a no-argument constructor in this situation either.

Comment: @user974349 - a Default Constructor in C++ has a very clear definition: it's a constructor which accepts no arguments (or all arguments have default arguments).

Comment: Not to be confused with a "defaulted default constructor", which is either the implicitly defined default constructor or a default constructor that is explicitly defaulted with `= default".

Comment: As a matter of fact, the misconception evoked by Stanley Lippman is not about the implicit declaration/definition of the default constructor, but about its synthesization (generation of some code for it). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9637074/20984).

Answer (score 4):

A default constructor is synthesized for every class that does not define one if:

- The code using the class needs one & only if
- There is no other constructor explicitly defined for the class by you.

Comment: when the users need one? A example? class A{} int main(){A a; return 0;}

Comment: yep. 'A a;' requires a default ctor. So one is generatoed.

Comment: The rules are rather strict here. `if (false) { A a; }` also requires a default ctor. The compiler doesn't look at the context where `a` is defined.

Comment: In fact, the default constructor is implicitly *defined* when it is used, but that does not mean it is *synthesized* (in the sense Stanley Lippman uses the word). Indeed, if the constructor is trivial, it does not involve any operations and there is no need to generate any code for it, nor to make any function call when constructing an instance of the class (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9637074/20984)).

Answer (score 3):

All the upvoted answers thus far seem to say approximately the same thing:

> A default constructor is synthesized for every class that does not have **any user-defined constructor**.

which is a modification of the statement in the question, which means

> A default constructor is synthesized for every class that does not have **a user-defined default constructor**.

The difference is important, but the statement is still wrong.

A correct statement would be:

> A default constructor is synthesized for every class that does not have any user-defined constructor **and for which all sub-objects are default-constructible in the context of the class**.

Here are some clear counter-examples to the first statement:

```
struct NoDefaultConstructor
{
     NoDefaultConstructor(int);
};

class Surprise1
{
     NoDefaultConstructor m;
} s1; // fails, no default constructor exists for Surprise1
```

`class Surprise1` has no user-defined constructors, but no default constructor is synthesized.

It doesn't matter whether the subobject is a member or a base:

```
class Surprise2 : public NoDefaultConstructor
{
} s2; // fails, no default constructor exists for Surprise2
```

Even if all subobjects are default-constructible, the default constructor has to be accessible from the composite class:

```
class NonPublicConstructor
{
protected:
    NonPublicConstructor();
};

class Surprise3
{
    NonPublicConstructor m;
} s3; // fails, no default constructor exists for Surprise3
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. `Surprise1` **does** have an implicitly-defined constructor, but this constructor tries to call `NoDefaultConstructor::NoDefaultConstructor()`, which does not exist. The synthesized default constructor invokes a non-existent function, hence the compiler error. In Comeau, when you compile your samples, the error message states that `no default constructor exists for class "NoDefaultConstructor"`, not that `no default constructor exists for class "Surprise"`.

Comment: GCC outputs `no matching function for call to ‘NoDefaultConstructor::NoDefaultConstructor()’`. I think these two compilers have it right, as the standard is quite clear on this point: `If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a default constructor is implicitly-declared.` (§12.1.5) What compiler did you use to test your samples?

Comment: @Luc: The compiler is trying to synthesize `Surprise1::Surprise1`, and it fails to do so.  To just says "the compiler synthesizes it" implies success.  Also, the standard says that in such cases the default constructor is implicitly defined as *deleted*.  It does not exist.

Comment: @Luc: Your other comment says that "synthesizes" means that "code is generated".  No code is generated here, because it would be illegal to do so.

Comment: I guess it depends what we mean by "code is generated". In Lippman's book, the implementation generates C code that is then compiled to machine code, so when he talks about code synthesis, he means that C code is generated. In our case, the C code could be generated but the compilation to machine code would fail. I don't know how this works on modern compilers, which does not use an intermediary C code: does the compiler generate an internal representation of the constructor ("synthesize" it), and then fails to transform that into machine code? Or does it fail when trying  to "generate"...

Comment: ...the internal representation, and provides an error that explains why it can't? I'm not enough versed into compiler intrinsics to answer. Anyway, that does not really change anything from a user point of view: whether `Suprise` has an invalid default constructor or no default constructor at all makes little difference. However, I'll be interested to read the paragraph of the standard (C++11, I guess?) you quote, could you provide a reference? +1 btw, as your answer provides an important precision.

Comment: @Luc: Since C has no notion of access control, I find the argument that the compiler synthesizes C code, which then fails to compile, utterly unconvincing.  Unfortunately my copy of C++11 is on my other computer, I can't find the particular section right now.

Comment: @Luc: It's 12.1p5, "A
defaulted default constructor for class X is defined as deleted if...".  Then p6: "A default constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is used"

Comment: You were right, the default constructor of `Surprise` is never defined, even before C++11. `Before the implicitly-declared default constructor for a class is implicitly defined, all the implicitly-declared default constructors for its base classes and its nonstatic data members shall have been implicitly defined.` (12.1p7). I just saw that the new standard made all this much more precise. Sorry for the long discussion!

Answer (score 0):

Yes a default constructor is always there by default if you don't define a constructor of your own (see the default constructor section [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)).

Comment: No, the book said that's the new ones' misunderstandings

Comment: If he defines another constructor, the default constructor isn't synthesised.

Comment: Sure, but you're referring to the default constructor, so "if you don't define one" means "if you don't define a default constructor".

Comment: @talnicolas - it is easy to misconstrue your statement as the incorrect "if you don't define one default constructor" rather than the more accurate "if you don't define one constructor."

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-257648.html

Quote:

The following sentense are got from the book "Inside the C++ object model" , written by Stanley B. Lippman.

> There are four characteristics of a class under which the compiler
>   needs to synthesize a default constructor for classes that declare no
>   constructor at all. The Standard refers to these as implicit,
>   nontrivial default constructors. The synthesized constructor fulfills
>   only an implementation need. It does this by invoking member object or
>   base class default constructors or initializing the virtual function
>   or virtual base class mechanism for each object. Classes that do not
>   exhibit these characteristics and that declare no constructor at all
>   are said to have implicit, trivial default constructors. In practice,
>   these trivial default constructors are not synthesized. ...
>   Programmers new to C++ often have two common misunderstandings:
>
> - That a default constructor is synthesized for every class that does
>     not define one
> - That the compiler-synthesized default constructor provides explicit
>     default initializers for each data member declared within the class
>
> As you have seen, neither of these is true.

Comment: Please do not answer with random URLs. A good answer can point to a "for more information" resource, but should stand by itself.