# does POD class object initialization require constructor?

Tags: c++

I read following links :-

[object initialized with and without parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402#620402)

[types of default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635772/is-it-true-that-a-default-constructor-is-synthesized-for-every-class-that-does-n)

[diff b/w value,zero and default intilization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat?lq=1)

I have some question which i want to clarify.

1) Given a POD class , say :-

```
class A{
        int val;
};
```

If i create an object of type A.

**A obj;** // will this call implicitly defined constructor provided by compiler ?
Now as far as my understanding in this case constructor is not called.is it correct?

**new A();** // value-initialize A, which is zero-initialization since it's a POD.
Now in this case will implicitly defined constructor provided by compiler ? Is there is any role of constructor for zero initializing the object?

If my understanding is wrong , could  you please give me an example where implicitly defined defined constructor is not called at all.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Correct. `obj.val` is not initialized.

2) This is a function declaration, not an initialization:

```
A obj(); // function obj() returning an A
```

If you did this,

```
A obj{};     //C++11
A obj = A(); // C++03 and C++11
```

`obj` would be *value-initialized*, and so would `obj.val`. This in turn means that `obj.val` would be *zero-initialized* (*value-initialization* means *zero-initialization* for built-in types).

Comment: so for A obj; will not call implicitly defined default constructor?

Comment: @user1057741 it will, but that won't result in any initialization of `val`. If your class had a member of a user defined type (say, an `std::string`), then its default constructor *would* be called.

Comment: could you please give me an example where implicitly defined default constructor is not called ?

Comment: @user1057741 No, I can't think of one at the moment.

Comment: does value-initialization results into zero-initialization every time ?

Comment: @user1057741 there are pathological cases where it doesn't. For example, if you have a class with a built-in data member, and you provide a default constructor that does not explicitly initialize it, value initializing that class does not zero-initialize the member. I put a contrived example [here](http://ideone.com/TqNYue). When I ran an optimized build of that on my platform, I get `-1924868947`. If you removed the default constructor, or used it to value-initialize `i`, then `i` would be zero initialized.

Comment: @ juanchopanza : thank you for the example, so if i am understanding it correctly , it will be value-initialized but because user have provided default constructor which does not do anything hence it will be remain uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

```
A obj;
```

It calls default constructor (or even not for optimization), however default constructor doesn't initialize it.

```
A obj();
```

It's a function declaration. No arguments and returns `A`.

```
A obj{};
```

Instead, you can use above code which sets `val` to zero.